# swift3 ドロワータイプのメニューライブラリを探しています

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

下の図のようなアプリを作りたいです。
アプリ起動時に毎回画面１を開き、画面１から遷移した画面２でドロワータイプのメニューを設置したいです。

REFrostedViewControllerライブラリで試してみたのですが起動時の画面にしか設置できないようです。

REFrostedViewController
https://github.com/romaonthego/REFrostedViewController

REFrostedViewControllerライブラリのようなドロワーメニューで、画面２に設置できるようなライブラリを教えていただけませんか。
または、REFrostedViewControllerライブラリを画面2へ設置する方法があればそちらも教えていただきたいです。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。
REFrostedViewControllerライブラリで画面2への設置をすることができました。

ありがとうございます。

Comment: @a.hayashiさん
突然すみません、全く同じところで詰まっておりまして、よければ解決方法を簡単で構いませんので、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。
どうぞご検討お願いします。

Comment: @KotaroHarada さん、こんにちは。
REFrostedViewControllerライブラリを使えているという前提でお話を進めて大丈夫でしょうか？

AppDelegate.swiftの
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {}の中に
DEMONavigationController(rootViewController:)を書いておられるでしょうか？

もし書いておられるようでしたら、
DEMONavigationController(rootViewController: HomeViewController())
このHomeViewController()というところを画面2の名前に変更します。
DEMONavigationController(rootViewController: 画面2の名前)
この一行でどの画面をroot画面にするのか設定しているようです。

ものすごく簡単にまとめましたが、これで解決できそうでしょうか？